# ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS' as the quota is on another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm currently getting a `ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'` as my quota is on another table.

I've executed the query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TS_QUOTAS;
```

I've got the following results:

```
TABLESPACE_NAME | BYTES | MAX_BYTES | MAX_BLOCKS | DROPPED
      DATA           0         -1          0          NO
```

My user has an unlimited quota however when executing an insert I'm unable to do this as it's looking at the USERS table. Any way to fix this?

UPDATE:

The default tablespace was users. The query below confirmed this.

```
SELECT PROPERTY_VALUE
FROM DATABASE_PROPERTIES
WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = 'DEFAULT_PERMANENT_TABLESPACE';
```

The solution to this problem is to change the tablespace to where I have the quota. Thanks to Alex Poole.

Comment: Add the table definition - seems like it's been created in the USERS tablespace instead of the DATA tablespace. Maybe USERS is your schema's default TS, and you need to specify DATA in the `create table`. Which TS do you actually want it in? If you have to create it in USERS then you will need to have a quota added to that too.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. My TS was Users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need to recreate you table [in the DATA tablespace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2126711):

```
drop table your_table;
create table your_table (...) tablespace data;
```

Or if you actually want it in the USERS tablespace, your DBA will need to [allow you to use space in that tablespace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4003.htm) as well:

```
alter user your_user quota unlimited on users;
```

Answer (score 1):

It look's like you have unlimmited quota on Tablespace DATA but no permission on Tablespace USERS. Ask your DBA to grant you quota on Tablespace USERS